# Visual Studio doesn't run my code properly

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I'm using Visual Studio code to write Java for school, and it runs my code really weird. So what happens is that my code, which is supposed to just print out "test" using super simple "System.out.println", runs in the terminal along with a list of all the directories used and it is really unorganized. This is what it looks like:

> PS C:\Users*myname*\Documents\Java\java_with_vscode> & 'C:\Users*myname*.vscode\extensions\vscjava.vscode-java-debug-0.21.0\scripts\launcher.bat' 'C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-11.0.4.11-hotspot\bin\java' '-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8' '-cp' 'C:\Users*myname*\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\workspaceStorage\0e6931a1b8b4239719709a0414b75a46\redhat.java\jdt_ws\java_with_vscode_e672b01a\bin' 'Hello'
>   test
>   PS C:\Users*myname*\Documents\Java\java_with_vscode>

So the code chows up after the huge blob of text, and it also works with user input as I tested before but I know for a fact this isn't how it is supposed to be displayed. I watched Youtube videos and for everyone, their code shows up in debug console, and for me my debug console is empty. The output tab is also empty, and when im either selected on output or debug console, it just automatically runs the code in the terminal. I am unsure why this happens, and searching for hours online didn't help, either this a problem unique to me or I'm being braindead and missing a really simple step. Either case, I would appreciate some help. How do I make it so that my code shows up in debug console how it is supposed to rather than in the terminal?

Thank you for your time.

I have redownloaded Visual Studio from Ninite and the official website.

I have added Java paths.

I have used the Java: quickstart option to make the files for a project and still doesn't work.

```
public class Hello {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("test");
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe this is how the new version works, I have the same behavior and haven’t bothered to research why since some things like user input works better now.

Answer (score 3):

> shows up in debug console how it is supposed to rather than in the
>   terminal

try to add `"console": "internalConsole"` in your **launch.json** like :

```
"configurations": [
           {
             "type": "java",
             "name": "CodeLens (Launch) - App",
             "request": "launch",
             "mainClass": "com.test.maven.App",
             "console": "internalConsole",
             "projectName": "my.app"
           }
         ]
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be useful to try to use an IDE other than VS Code that is more suitable for Java such as Netbeans or Eclipse which are free to download.  This may enable your code to run more smoothly.