# Command 'cmd' not found, but there are 16 similar ones

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to run a java program on windows in VSCODE. When I click the run button at the top it opens the Java Process Console and runs the following command:
 `$  cmd /C "c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\vscjava.vscode-java-debug-0.31.0\scripts\launcher.bat "C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-11.0.10.9-hotspot\bin\java.exe" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 @C:\Users\jbree\AppData\Local\Temp\cp_7gau2431e54dxprosf092viw9.argfile com.example.restservice.RestServiceApplication "`

It then prints out: `Command 'cmd' not found, but there are 16 similar ones.`, and I'm not too sure what to do afterwards.

Comment: What is the output of `echo %PATH%`? Is `C:\Windows\System32` included?

Comment: It is when I run it in a cmd, but that is not a command in the java process console.

Comment: Can you post the error screenshot? Have you tried to set powershell as default terminal? Does it still goes wrong in powershell?

Answer (score 4):

I just ran into this exact issue! After some debugging, I found out it's because my terminal (in VS Code) was running off of WSL.

Make sure to check which terminal you're using! If you're trying to run Java locally, then you can configure a default shell ie. bash.

Let me know if this helps.

Edit: I also found this, not sure if it will help, but here you go!
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58058378/11060097

Answer (score 2):

your java debugger is using wsl.   and most likely your java is installed on windows.  not linux on windows.    to fix this for me, i changed the settings for java debugging to use the external console.  settings->java debugger->externalTerminal .    this will then use the "external windows" setting for vscode. which should use cmd.exe (the windows shell, no linux).

Answer (score 1):

I've looked everywhere and could not find a way to tell VSCode to use `cmd.exe ...` instead of `cmd ...` to run java when using a WSL terminal.

As others stated, you can use an external terminal (which will be `cmd.exe`), but if you'd like to keep using an integrated terminal in VSCode, the best (well, the only) way I found is to add an alias.

In your .bashrc file, simply add:

```
alias cmd="cmd.exe"
```

And it will work :)

Answer (score 0):

This error happens because you probably have wsl has your standard terminal but it's probably configured to launch cmd using a windows path.

WSL won't understand what that windows path is, so you need to change it using a path structure it can understand

So

1. hit **Ctrl+,** to hit the Settings screen
2. type in **terminal** to see all the terminal settings
   You will see an option called ***Terminal> External:Windows Exec***
3. Change *C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe* to **/mnt/c/Windows/System32/cmd.exe**

[image]

I had this error too and came here initially but I managed to figure out it was an incompatible path issue that was the cause.

Comment: careful with this method.  this is still using wsl, and trying to use wsl to launch the windows shell.   better to just pick a shell.  and for java on windows, your prolly want the windows shell (cmd.exe) .  no wsl.